# Are "blindman" and "blind man" both correct?

Tags: orthography, archaicisms

Which is the correct spelling: *blindman* or *blind man*? Both are frequently used on the web, but *blindman* is marked as incorrect on the Internet and by Microsoft Word, and it is not found in most dictionaries.

Example:

> There is a blindman/blind man in the street.

The Free Dictionary has the following definitions

> ***blindman***: Word not found in the Dictionary and Encyclopedia. [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blindman)
>
> **blindman**
>   plural *blindmen*
>   chiefly British
>   [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blindman)

Comment: What is the source of your quote?  Which dictionaries or other references have you checked, and what did they say?  If you read the [help center tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) you can find out more about how to write good questions.

Comment: @jejorda2 Why do you assume I didn't check dictionaries? Isn't that easier that asking question here? blindman: Word not found in the Dictionary and Encyclopedia. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blindman   --- "Blind Man" is a song by American hard rock band Aerosmith. http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/blind+man  ----blindman
plural blindmen
chiefly British https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blindman

Comment: "Blindman" is not idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @Jooya you would think checking a dictionary would be easier than asking a question, but a lot of people still ask here without checking.  That's one of the reasons we ask people to "show their research" in the question; it helps us to understand more specifically what they are confused about or uncertain of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ***blindman, n*** the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20253?rskey=3SYpH3&result=2#eid) says:

> Now written as two words.
>
> c1325   Chron. Eng. 769 in J. Ritson Anc. Eng. Metrical Romanceës II.
>   302   Ant a blindmon hede sihte.
>
> 1600   Shakespeare Much Ado about Nothing ii. i. 187   You strike like
>   the blindman

The OED isn't always up to the minute in its quotations, but it is usually not more than 400 years behind! It is safe to conclude that *blindman* is not in current usage.

Answer (score 3):

Blind man is correct, there is no such word as blindman, similarly dumb man or deaf man.

Comment: Do you mean in American English. Becasue Webster Dictionary says: blindman plural blindmen chiefly British merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blindman

Answer (score 1):

The only occurrences of "blindman" that I can find [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=blindman&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22blindman%22) are in reference to the [1971 movie of that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindman).

It's not American English, it's not British English, it's not English.

Comment: What about Webster dictionary then?

Comment: @Jooya - OED says, "Now written as two words."